# Removing exe from windows startmenu quick launch

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, startmenu

For work we have two shortcuts that get installed to the start menu with both of them pointing to the same exe (but the second with different command line arguments).

Some times windows will pick the second shortcut to display in the start menu hot program list which is bad because it causes a full update of the application.

Is there a way to tell windows not to show that shortcut in the start menu list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in fact Raymond Chen [just wrote about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/11/10127763.aspx):

> You can set the [`System.App­User­Model.Exclude­From­Show­In­New­Install` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391568%28VS.85%29.aspx) to `VARIANT_TRUE` to tell the Start menu, "I am not the primary entry point for the program; I'm a secondary shortcut, like a help file."

Sample code ([`CCoInitialize` class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/20/135841.aspx)):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

// class 3CCoInitialize incorporated here by reference

int __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR **argv)
{
 // error checking elided for expository purposes
 CCoInitialize init;
 CComPtr<IShellLink> spsl;
 spsl.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink);
 spsl->SetPath(TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\LitWare\\LWUpdate.exe"));
 PROPVARIANT pvar;
 pvar.vt = VT_BOOL;
 pvar.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;
 CComQIPtr<IPropertyStore>(spsl)->SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall, pvar);
 CComQIPtr<IPersistFile>(spsl)->Save(L"LitWare Update.lnk", TRUE);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats only for exe highlight and plus how does that work with two shortcuts to the same exe?

Comment: @Lodle: The property only applies to the shortcut, not the exe

Comment: @Lodle: No, not on a shortcut in the users startmenu

Comment: Thanks, Got it working but i had to delete the old shortcut and create a completely new shortcut using the com api. What a pain in the ass. Cant change my down vote to an up vote as well :(

Answer (score 2):

You'll find the documentation for those settings here: [Application User Model IDs (AppUserModelIDs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459.aspx). Specifically, you're looking for the section entitled **"Exclusion Lists for Taskbar Pinning and Recent/Frequent Lists"**. The applicable portion is reprinted below:

> Applications, processes, and windows can choose to make themselves unavailable for pinning to the taskbar or for inclusion in the Start menu's MFU list. There are three mechanisms to accomplish this:
>
> 1. Add the `NoStartPage` entry to the application's registration as shown here:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\Example.exe\NoStartPage
>    ```
>
>    The data associated with the `NoStartPage` entry is ignored. Only the presence of the entry is required. Therefore, the ideal type for `NoStartPage` is `REG_NONE`.
>
>    Note that any use of an explicit AppUserModelID overrides the `NoStartPage` entry. If an explicit AppUserModelID is applied to a shortcut, process, or window, it becomes pinnable and eligible for the Start menu MFU list.
> 2. Set the [`System.AppUserModel.PreventPinning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd561983.aspx) property on windows and shortcuts. This property must be set on a window before the [`PKEY_AppUserModel_ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391569.aspx) property.
> 3. Add an explicit `AppUserModelID` as a value under the following registry subkey as shown here:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileAssociation\NoStartPageAppUserModelIDs\AppUserModelID
>    ```
>
> Each entry is a `REG_NULL` value with the name of the AppUserModelID. Any AppUserModelID found in this list is not pinnable and not eligible for inclusion in the Start menu MFU list.

Comment: But the shortcuts use the same exe. Want the first shortcut to be pin able but not the second.

Comment: The second point (`System.AppUserModel.PreventPinning` property) talks about schortcuts, too.